# Android Studio - Voice search - Crashing on saying number 2 and 4

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, voice

I have an activity that has voice function. which lets you say 4 words and these words are added into an array. I am want only the second and the last word.

I am converting the second word into a string and the last word into an int (last word is always a number from 1-5).

The code is working fine as long as I don't say 2 or 4. as soon I say those two numbers the app crashes.

how can I fix this?

I tried of thinking of inserting an if statement. for example - if string contains word for, four then it = 4. (rough code).

I have posted the code and stack trace below.

```
public class Report extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;
private TextView mVoiceInputTv;
private ImageButton mSpeakBtn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.report);


    mVoiceInputTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.voiceInput);
    mSpeakBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
    mSpeakBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startVoiceInput();
        }
    });

    final String carreg = mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString();


}

private void startVoiceInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "e.g- Report fpg563 rating 3");
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {

    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                mVoiceInputTv.setText(result.get(0));

            }
            break;
        }

    }
    if(mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString().contains("report")) {
        input();

    }
}


public void input() {

    String test = mVoiceInputTv.getText().toString();
    String[] ms = test.split(" ");
    List<String> selectedWords = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < ms.length; i++) {
        selectedWords.add(ms[i]);


        final String carreg = ms[1];
        final String newrating = ms[3];
        final int rating = Integer.parseInt(newrating);





        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                    if (success) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Report.this, Report.class);
                        Report.this.startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Report.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Reporting Failed")
                                .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                .create()
                                .show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        };
        Report_request registerRequest = new Report_request(carreg, rating, responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Report.this);
        queue.add(registerRequest);
    }
}

}
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
10-25 17:45:41.449 32501-32501/com.example.naveen.loginregister E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.naveen.loginregister, PID: 32501
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent {  launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 }(has extras) }} to activity {com.example.naveen.loginregister/com.example.naveen.loginregister.Report}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "for"
      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4472)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4515)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "for"
      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
      at com.example.naveen.loginregister.Report.input(Report.java:103)
      at com.example.naveen.loginregister.Report.onActivityResult(Report.java:85)
      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7256)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4468)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4515) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

whats up with this downvotes? im asking an honest question. ofcourse the grammer might be bad. but im still learning english. u want me to go to a english classs before i post a question?

Comment: What is in stack trace, please share. (No downvote)

Comment: what do you mean stack trace? im still learning java. so im not really sure what you mean.

Comment: The crash log shown in LogCat (eclipse or Android Studio) after every crash.

Comment: oh right. hold up

Comment: You better read this before asking your next question; https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And in light of these guidelines, please update your above question with all details required to understand and solve it, otherwise the question is gonna be closed.

Comment: well what else you want me to put? the code?

Comment: I think, you can solve the question now, please check this line in stack trace and think, `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "for" at `

Comment: that what i have said in my quesstion. when i say the number 4. the app thinks im saying for or four. since the value saving is int format. the app crashes because the value is a string. i want an answer or guide that will allow me convert words liek for or four to 4.

Comment: Well, say **four**, not **for**. ;-) Have you heard about exception handling, you must implement it there. If you don't know anything about it, please take some Java basics tutorial.

Comment: lol. i tried to say 4 in different slangs but failed :c . 1, 2 and 5 works fine :). and no idk much exception handling.

Comment: Please learn about it (exception handling), you can't write any useful code without handling the exceptions. In your above question's case, please catch `java.lang.NumberFormatException` and show some friendly message to users and ask them to correct their input.

Comment: Since you put efforts in your question, and made it correct, I edited and upvoted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is must be happening because 2 is also the word "to" or "too" which is not going to be convertable into an int unless you are catching those cases.  Similarly, as you pointed out 4 is probably being converted to the word "for" which again won't convert to an int unless you specifically catch that case.

I think you're on the right track, catching those cases where the voice to text is going to hand you a word that sounds like a number but isn't one.

BUT if you want your code to not crash you need to prepare for any possible input. So you should be catching the exception if it is thrown and then doing the right thing.

```
try {
    final int rating = Integer.parseInt(newrating);
} catch ( NumberFormatException e ) {
    //uhoh couldn't get the number 
    //prompt the user to try again or 
    //do something else that makes sense
}
```

Comment: u are a smart guy :)

Comment: Catching generic exception is not always good, specially if you know the exception thrown.

Comment: Updated answer to specific exception thrown by parseInt (NumberFormatException)

Comment: yea. i still get same problem. is it possible to do a if statement? for example. add array[3] (the last word) into a string. if the string contain the word for then create a new int value with the number 4. something like that?

Comment: For catching the words like "for" I would just skip the parseInt entirely.  Something like if ms[3].equals("for") { rating=4;}  to get the rating before you do the parseInt then check if the rating is set and greater than 0 and if not do the parseInt try catch statement

Comment: i tried to implement if statement and it doesnt crash but nothing is being saved

Comment: Can you show your code that's failing to do what you expect?  And I'll have a look.

Comment: oh i fixed it by using if statement :)